# how to reduce html video player size in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used bootstrap to have responsive video , but problem is I have only 2 sizes

```
class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"
```

and

```
class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3"
```

these are really huge. how can i change width and height manually , if i try with this

`style="width:400px ; height:400px"`

the video is re sized but the responsive does not work. 
please help me .

this is my code

```
  <div align="center"  class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="width:400px;height:400px">

<video   class="embed-responsive-item"  controls>
  <source src="<?php echo str_replace("../../../../","",$subvalue->video);?>" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</div>
```

i need like this

[image]

but after adding style width and  height i get like this

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Responsive Embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed) classes only set the aspect-ratio (use `.embed-responsive-16by9` for a 16x9 video and `.embed-responsive-4by3` for a 4x3 one). They'll take up 100% of the width of their containing block.

In order to give them a width, you'll only need to add a container, for example `.sizer`, that has a `width` set.

```css
.sizer {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="sizer">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" autoplay controls></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option is to add it inside a Bootstrap grid like this

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <video src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" autoplay controls></video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Never try to add the `width` and `height` properties directly to the element with the class `.embed-responsive` as that will break its responsiveness. It is not needed to add `.embed-responsive-item` unless you want an item different from `iframe`, `embed`, `object` or `video`.

Comment: You can also surround it with a regular bootstrap grid, using e.g. `.col-xs-6`, or surround it with a container `div` that has a percentual width. What kind of responsiveness are you exactly looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Go grab fitvids js and as long as you start with width and height dimensions fitvids will make that video responsive: http://fitvidsjs.com